# Toggle Comments Keyboard Shortcut (CTRL + /) Does Not Work

Tags: sql, sas, teradata

I use SAS Enterprise Guide and Teradata Studio Express to code for my day job. WindowsOS.

I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> shortcut to comment lines of code out in both apps. Suddenly, this shortcut has stopped working. I've checked all my keyboard and Code Shortcut Key settings in both apps and nothing seems out of place!

All other shortcuts seem to work in both apps, common ones I use like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (copy), <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (cut), <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste) etc

I've got no idea why the 'comment out' shortcut is unable to register. Anyone else encounter this same annoying issue?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is some app (perhaps newly installed or updated) may have registered the key combo as a global hot key.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> will pack your line in `/*` and `*/`

If you have selected a range, Enterprise Guide will do that with every line from which you selected any character.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> will unpack them

Comment: Tried that out and it does not work. 

I looked into the 'Enhanced editor keys' on SAS EG and commenting out lines of code is CTRL + / , uncommenting out is CTRL + SHIFT + /.

I use a laptop at home and this keyboard does not allow for this shortcut to work. When I'm at work, on a Dell PC Desktop, this short cut works. I have a feeling my laptop keyboard settings may be playing a part but I've checked FnLock, HotKeys (none related to CTRL + /) to no success. 

Thanks for the response.

Comment: I see, on an `azerty` keyboard, `/` is [shift] + `:` .

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define it again.

1. Go to  Tools-->options-->Enhanced Editor Keys
2. Select the Command "Comment the selection...." and press Assign keys
3. within "Press new shortcut key:" enter the ctrl + : key and press assign